# Xamarin FacebookClient

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms and want to integrate Facebook in android app. I want to pull the feed from a page like https://www.facebook.com/HyundaiIndia

I have installed `Xamarin.Facebook` from Nuget. It doesn't have a `FacebookClient` object as mentioned in here: https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebook-sdk

Then I found the `Xamarin.Facebook` and `Xamarin.FacebookBolts` namespaces which I included, but I still didn't get `FacebookClient`. Instead I found `Xamarin.Facebook.XAndroid.Facebook` and I created an instance:

```
Xamarin.Facebook.XAndroid.Facebook fb = new Xamarin.Facebook.XAndroid.Facebook(FacebookAppId);
```

But this object doesn't have `GetTaskAsync`. How do I pull down the feeds in Xamarin?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same experience trying following the article you mentioned.
The component created by Outercurve Foundation (Facebook.dll version 6.2.1)
needs that you reference Facebook.dll and you include it in your file like this:

```
using Facebook;
```

Don't confuse it with:

```
using Xamarin.Facebook;
```

**EDIT**

I finally found a bit of time for a more complete answer and since the example on the link
doesn't specify how to obtain the AccessToken (called userToken in the facebook-sdk component page example linked in the question) I'm posting one of the possible solutions.
This one works for me and doesn't require any other library or component (but the one already mentioned in the question).

```
using Xamarin.Auth;
using Facebook;

string FaceBookAppId = "YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID";
string AccessToken;
string OauthTokenSecret;
string OauthConsumerKey;
string OauthConsumerSecret;

void GetFBTokens()
{
    var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(FaceBookAppId,
       "",
       new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
       new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
      );

    auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
        {
           eventArgs.Account.Properties.TryGetValue("access_token", out AccessToken);
           eventArgs.Account.Properties.TryGetValue("oauth_token_secret", out OauthTokenSecret);
           eventArgs.Account.Properties.TryGetValue("oauth_consumer_key", out OauthConsumerKey);
           eventArgs.Account.Properties.TryGetValue("oauth_consumer_secret", out OauthConsumerSecret);
        }
    };
}
```

//Now we can use the example of the link.

```
void PostToMyWall ()
{
    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient (AccessToken);
    string myMessage = "Hello from Xamarin";

    fb.PostTaskAsync ("me/feed", new { message = myMessage }).ContinueWith (t => {
        if (!t.IsFaulted) {
            string message = "Great, your message has been posted to you wall!";
            Console.WriteLine (message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've added the Xamarin.Auth. Now for use the FacebookClient what nugget should i pick?

Comment: If I remember right the above code use The Outercurve Foundation one.

Comment: Can't import the Outercurve Foundation because of PCL profile compatibility. Whats was the profile you were using in your PCL?

Comment: just out of curiousity. From the Facebook app page side. Do you need to enable "publish_actions" to actually post message on your wall? Or is the code you show here enought to actually post a message?

Comment: Yes you need to enable "publish_actions" if you use an app which was created after April 30th, 2014. Have a look at the Facebook Login Review FAQs to get an idea of the review process. Let us know if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 editions of Facebook SDK, one is binding for official SDK, another is from Outercurve Foundation.

Looks like you're using this one: [the "official" binding](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid) , so check the documentation on this link.